# Change param name to nested resource parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this routes:

```
resources :tags do
      resources :comments
end
```

so the `:create` action for the comments has the following form

```
tag_comments POST   /tags/:tag_id/comments(.:format)
```

how can i change the paramenter name from `:tag_id` to `:commentable_id`?

Comment: what wrong with the solutions below ?

Answer (score 2):

```
map.tags do
  resources :comments, :path_prefix => '/tags/:commentable_id'
end
```

or via before_filter

```
before_filter :tag2commentable

private
def tag2commentable
  params[:commentable_id] = params[:tag_id] unless params[:tag_id].blank?
end
```

put it in your controller

Answer (score 1):

One of these may be what you want:

```
map.resources :commentables, :as => "tags", :collection => :comments
map.resources :commentables, :as => "tags", :has_many => :comments
```

I suppose the latter being correct, which resolves to:

```
$ rake routes
commentable_comments GET /tags/:commentable_id/comments(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
...
```

But I suppose your model relations may be screwed somehow as this makes no sense. Do mind to amend your post and add info about your model relations?

I suppose having

```
map.resources :commentables, :has_many => :tags
```

or

```
map.resources :taggables, :has_many => :comments
```

would make more sense:

```
 commentable_tags GET /commentables/:commentable_id/tags(.:format) {:action=>"index", :controller=>"tags"}
taggable_comments GET /taggables/:taggable_id/comments(.:format)   {:action=>"index", :controller=>"comments"}
```

Comment: I think the problem with defining the resource name as something other than your model name is that polymorphic url methods will fail. At least that's my experience.